# How to list all documents/words per topic in bert topic modelling?

Tags: python, dataframe, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I read the docs, but i can see the topics only show 3 or 4 documents per topic whereas the count is 2000+, is there a way i can see all the assigned documents, instead of three/four documents per topic?
For example: i want to see all the 2555 documents in the below picture, and get all words under the name column, not just first 3, 4 words I tried many things, but it doesn't work[image]

Answer (score 2):

as I understood you want to see `n_words` of the model and also documents representing the specific topics. First of all, you can list all topics b following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,
                       'display.max_columns', None,
                       'display.precision', 3,
                       ):
    print(freq1)
```

with this, you will see all the topics you have on your model.

In order to get `n_words` from topic 3 you can run this command:

```py
model1.get_topic(3)
```

and you will get

```
[('hood', 0.08646080854070591),
 ('fort', 0.07903592661513956),
 ('terrorist', 0.04050269806508548),
 ('muslim', 0.0404965762204116),
 ('ft', 0.04046989026050265),
 ('militari', 0.03581303765985982),
 ('armi', 0.025703775870144486),
 ('base', 0.025620172464129863),
 ('islam', 0.024491265378088094),
 ('attack', 0.02280540444895898)]
```

output like this, `n_words` with its **c-TF-IDF** score.

you can also get all topics with their own `n_words` by running:

```py
model1.get_topics()
```

if you want to get documents that represents topics you can run:

```py
model1.get_representative_docs(3)
```

where the output will be like:

```
['wouldnt fort hood islam terror attack radic jihadist',
 'wasnt fort hood consid terrorist attack',
 'kind gun use fort hood']
```

Comment: Hi, thank u for the solution :) but i am still getting for topic 0 ,only 4 output , i.e, gun, law, people, shoot not the entire list of 2555 documents, could you please tell me a way to do so? i am not sure where am i going wrong :(

Comment: so for topic 4, you have only 4 outputs. can you show me the entire code fragment, or how you filter out topic 0-s and e.t.c.? Thanks

Comment: i am using simple bert, all i needed was the name column to show me the alloted count documents...for eg in topic 0 it should show all 834 documents in the name column. .get_topic gives me top 10 words.

Comment: I can see that you are using some Jupiter notebooks. if it is colab much easier, can you share it with me so I can help you more?

Comment: Hi, could you share me your mail id or something? so that i can share you the collaB file, thank you :)

Comment: demetredzmanashvili@gmail.com Thanks